# MSTeams Tab ASP.NET Core MVC App Authentication with Bearer Token Unauthorized Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to make a MS Teams tab application using ASP.NET Core Web App MVC. The app needs a graph client to access SharePoint resources.

I have already succeeded in implementing this example from Microsoft: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-sso/csharp

Therefore the app registration should be configured correctly.

But with the authentication of said tutorial I can't inject the Microsoft Graph Client in the "ConfigureServices" method.

Therefore I tried to implement this Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/teams?tutorial-step=4 as a MVC app. But now when I try to fetch a method with authorization I keep getting the the 401 error.

In the Configure Method the "app.UseAuthentication()" is also before "app.UseAuthorization()"

This is my "ConfigureServices" Method

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
    }
```

This is my JS in index.cshtml

```
    (function () {
        if (microsoftTeams) {
            microsoftTeams.initialize();

            microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
                successCallback: (token) => {
                    $('<code/>', {
                        text: token,
                        style: 'word-break: break-all;'
                    }).appendTo('#tab-container');
                    fetch('/GetTest', {
                        method: 'get',
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/text",
                            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
                        }
                    }).then(response => {
                        response.text()
                            .then(body => {
                                $('#tab-container').empty();
                                $('<code/>', {
                                    text: body
                                }).appendTo('#tab-container');
                            });
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                        renderError(error);
                    });
                },
                failureCallback: (error) => {
                    renderError(error);
                }
            });
        }
    })();
```

And here is the "GetTest" Method I call

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("GetTest")]
    public async Task<string> GetTest()
    {
        // This verifies that the access_as_user scope is
        // present in the bearer token, throws if not
        HttpContext.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(apiScopes);

        // To verify that the identity libraries have authenticated
        // based on the token, log the user's name
        _logger.LogInformation($"Authenticated user: {User.GetDisplayName()}");

        try
        {
            // TEMPORARY
            // Get a Graph token via OBO flow
            var token = await _tokenAcquisition
                .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[]{
                    "User.Read",
                    "Sites.ReadWrite.All" });

            // Log the token
            _logger.LogInformation($"Access token for Graph: {token}");
            return "{ \"status\": \"OK\" }";
        }
        catch (MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Consent required");
            // This exception indicates consent is required.
            // Return a 403 with "consent_required" in the body
            // to signal to the tab it needs to prompt for consent
            HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            await HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("consent_required");
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error occurred");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In this state of the app the method should now return with the consent required 403 error but I only get the 401 Unauthorized error.

What I am not sure about is if I can use the same Autherization as in the tutorial because my Project is a MVC Project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this topic, but I think you're trying to combine two different and  incompatible approaches together. You don't need to do the steps in your second tutorial because Teams SSO is already giving you what you need to do the basic Graph access. Importantly, the token that Teams SSO gives you can NOT be used directly against Graph, it needs to be exchanged for an "on behalf of" (OBO) token, which can be used as the Bearer token for Graph calls.

The sample you've linked has code to do exactly this for you though, in the `GetAccessTokenOnBehalfUserAsync` method in 'SSOAuthHelper'. If you want to see it in action, look at the `GetUserAccessToken` method in 'HomeController'. Instead of just returning it, like this `GetUserAccessToken` method does, you can actually *use* it in your controller method. For instance, see `GetUserData` in [this sample](https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/blob/main/samples/tab-sso/src/dotnet/Controllers/ApiAuthController.cs).

Comment: @davbue - Does the help provided by Hilton resolves your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not but I found out that even when using the exact solution of the Microsoft Graph Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/teams I get a 401 error. Maybe the issue is connected to the environment. Anyway I will most likely proceed with contacting the Microsoft Support.